# Removing bluetooth usage from Flutter project

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

I have a handful of apps that are all for the same company and use the same data. They all share a package that I wrote that handles a lot of the heavy lifting that I didn't want to have to re-write such as API calls and also serialisable models for all of the database tables. This package also features a built in bluetooth client that can handle discovering and controlling one of our products, so this shared package requires flutter_blue in the pubspec.yaml, even though I only use it one of the apps (I may need it in the future)

My problem is that I don't want to have to specify NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription in my Info.plist however app store connect claims it's a missing purpose string because my app is referencing CoreBluetooth.

How can I get around this? I'm assuming that I'm going to need to abstract the bluetooth client into it's own package however if you have any other ideas that may be less strenuous for the mean time as I'm quite pressed for time, that would be great, thank you.